# A Modem over MSTSC and Microsoft Activation

Tags: remote-desktop, modem, windows-activation

I have a large number of servers remotely located , many of which are VMs, all of which have no connection to Microsoft - so I've investigated if I can add a Modem physically connected to a  laptop and then use that at the prompt where it says use a Modem[image: Modem prompt]
Its been a long time - but I hope a modem just shows up as an extra Com port and 
MSTSC says it can redirect serial ports.

So my first questions is related to getting a modem,  am I going in the correct direction looking at a Mobile phone - or should i get a "real" modem.  Or perhaps a USB to serial with something else?

I've only just started investigating this and I think I'd need to resolve all of the following

1. Get a Modem connected to my Laptop
2. Make the Modem work on the digital systems
3. Make the Modem available to the Terminal service server from the client
4. Get the activation to use it

for the last well - I hope the rest means it will work - for 3 - MSTSC says it can redirect a serial port , so I'm left with 1 and 2 at work its VOIP so I assume I'll need a digital modem , at home - its analogue.So maybe my Cell phone will do this - I have a LG-H990ds I've used blue tooth and I see no Modem option - but two Unknown Services

[image: Bluetooth servicces]

USB cable tether appears to have a CDC Serial device - so I'm hoping that can be a modem - but its missing a driver - I can look at fixing that - but I'm not even sure its what I need

[image: LG Phone]

But then it does not appear in ports

[image]

Comment: ...have you considered AD-based or KMS-based activation first?

Comment: Well ... I implemented a KMS server for Excel as the clients where cloned VMs so nothing else would work (I think)  - The problem is the controlled environment we have means implementing another service/server takes years.  I just activated four new machines and I was looking for a quick fix .  You are right thats a better long term plan - I'll have to look at how

Comment: Before going for such a convoluted way either just give them Internet Access temporarily (essentially what you're planning to do anyway), use a telephone activation or setup a KMS. If you already got one in place you might actually be able to use that one.